# An error occurred (MalformedPolicy) when calling the PutBucketPolicy operation: Policy has invalid resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to make my s3 bucket public through cil, made changes everywhere but still getting error
"An error occurred (MalformedPolicy) when calling the PutBucketPolicy operation: Policy has invalid resource"

```
{
    "Id": "MyPolicy",
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadForGetBucketObjects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::task1y/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Can anyone suggest me how to solve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to SO!please share your policy and error as code and not image

Comment: Are you putting this bucket policy on a bucket named `task1y`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation the policy should match the below where `examplebucket` is the bucket name you're attaching the policy to.

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"PublicRead",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

This error you're receiving indicates that the bucket you're attaching this policy does not share the same name. In other words your resource can only be attached to a bucket named `task1y`.

Answer (score 1):

Some resources like ListBucket accept the arn with the full name like "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name", while GetObject or PutObjects expects a /* after the bucket_name. Change the ARNs according to the service and it should work now!